# Crypting/decrypting user passwords used for basic auth in Django

Tags: django, security, authentication, encryption, hash

I have a Django application. Via the app, users can access a third party API which uses basic auth credentials. I was planning on adding a section where user can add their credentials to said Api, which would then be stored to the database as a basic auth header. But then I facepalmed as obviously encoding them as base64 can be decoded to plain text.

What would be the best way to achieve a encrypting/decrypting mechanism in Django for this purpose? In this case, the credentials would be encrypted when saved to the database and encrypted when they are fetched from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give [Django encrypted fields](https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-model-fields/) a try.

An alternative is [Django Searchable Encrypted Fields](https://pypi.org/project/django-searchable-encrypted-fields/) which adds some functionality.

There might be more...

In general you should look for the most used and scrutinzed solutions whenever cryptography and security are relevant, don't invent secrurity yourself!

And keep in mind that safe storage of the encryption key is very important here.

Comment: Thanks. Django encrypted fields actually works great for my purpose. I'll save the encrypting key using azure key vault.